# List of formulas to choose from randomly

Tags: math-mode

I have a list of formulas, suppose y=x and y=x^2 and y=x^3.

I want to choose one of these formulas randomly in a foreach loop and add random integers or doubles to the left and right side of them.

The finished product will be bunch of different formulas printed with different numbers suppose

2x^2+3

x+4

15+x^3-4

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which LaTeX format do you use -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX?